# Google Spreadsheets SUMIF/SUMIFS according to a another column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have two columns:

- Billing date : date
- Billing amount : currency

I have another static cell where I want to sum all the *Billing amount* values, but only if the date in *Billing date* is greater or equal to now.

I have been looking into `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS`, but from what I gathered, these can only operate on ranges, not on a another column per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "<=" &TODAY(), C:C)
```

Where `A` is the date column and `C` is the amount column.

[Credit](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/03/15/sumif-google-sheets/#sumif-dates)